# Debug same project with 2 builds on device iphone ios sdk?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 2 version of the same project on my machine. Both have same unique bundle identifier. These are because i have 2 different version of the same application. I was wondering of instead I uninstall each version every time and re debug the actually desired version. If there is anyway to do this except than creating another project with different project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create another "build target" within the same Xcode project then configure it with a unique bundle id.

Comment: great will give a try :)